# Overriding indexers and using methods in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods, indexer

I have a class Season and class Episode. Class Season inherits class Episode.
My class Episode has this method:

```
        public void AddView(double rating)
    {
        viewerCount++;
        ratingSum += rating;
        if (rating > this.largestRating)
            this.largestRating = rating;
    }
```

My class Season has a list of episodes:

```
public Episode[] episodes { get; private set; }
```

I overrided the indexer of class Season so it returns the indexed episode in the list:

```
        public object this[int i]
    {
        get { return episodes[i]; }
    }
```

So when I do this in the program:

```
        Console.WriteLine(season[5]);
        Console.WriteLine(episodes[5]);
```

I get the same output.
Meanwhile, when I try to call methods on those episodes, episodes[5] allows me to call function AddView, but season[5] does not allow me to.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'AddView' and no accessible extension 
method 'AddView' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using 
directive or an assembly reference?)    OOP-DZ2 C:\Users\patri\source\repos\OOP-DZ2\OOP- 
DZ2\Program.cs  22  Active
```

How can I override the indexer, so I can access my list of Episode objects inside the Season object and call methods on it?

SOLVED
My indexer was overrided wrongly, it returned object instead of class Episode. Thanks.

Comment: Your indexer returns an object, it should return `Episode` I guess?

Comment: I think you are trying to get the object season and episode with the same indexer right?

Comment: you used this keyword, and this refer the present class , you should write indexer on different classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class **Season** should not be the base class of **Episode**, but just a container. In fact, you say "`Class Season inherits class Episode`" which does not make sense to me, and later you correctly state that "`My class Season has a list of episodes`".

> > I overrided the indexer of class Season so it returns the indexed episode in the list:

```
public object this[int i]
{
    get { return episodes[i]; }
}
```

Operators are not overriden. You overload their normal behaviour in order to adapt them to your class, but they are not overriden in the C# sense of rewrite them in a derived class. Maybe this confusion made you return an `object` instead of the correct **Episode** class.

```
public Episode this[int i]
{
    get { return episodes[i]; }
}
```

> Meanwhile, when I try to call methods on those episodes, episodes[5] allows me to call function `AddView`, but season[5] does not allow me to.

This is regular behaviour. I guess episodes[5] is an array of objects of class **Episode**, while `Season[5]` just returns an object.

```
class Episode {
}

class Season {
    public Episode this[int i]
    {
        get { return episodes[i]; }
    }

    List<Episode> episodes;
}
```